# How can I upgrade code for "CCLabelBMFont::purgeCachedData" in cocos2d v3.7 ?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

How can I upgrade code for "CCLabelBMFont::purgeCachedData" in cocos2d v3.7 ? 
Now in 3.7 it don't have "CCLabelBMFont" or "LabelBMFont"

All font display use Label class. But Label don't contain like "purgeCachedData" function.

Comment: try using `FontFNT::purgeCachedData()`

Comment: @musikov thanks, but it don't work on v3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cocos2dx 3.7
FontAtlasCache::purgeCachedData();